# When dismissing a View Controller, it ignores rotation rules

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a VC being presented with a navigation controller. Neither should auto rotate and neither of them do while on the screen. But if I dismiss VC2 while in landscape mode, VC1 will be in landscape mode..

This is what I have:
VC1:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                    initWithRootViewController:VC2];
    navigationController.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle=UIBarStyleDefault;
    navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
    navigationController.delegate=self;
    [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}


- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

VC2:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

I also have a category on UINavigationController which has helped me set orientation on other screens.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    if ([self.topViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(shouldAutorotate)]) {
        return [self.topViewController shouldAutorotate];
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {

    if ([self.topViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation)]) {

        return [self.topViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
    }

    return self.interfaceOrientation;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    if ([self.topViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(supportedInterfaceOrientations)]) {
        return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    }

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```